# ggrepel: Change start point of segments

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am making a graph, with labels given by ggrepel. I have arranged it so that all the labels are at the far side of the graph, so as to not obscure any of the data. The issue is that the segments are winding up behind some of the other labels, making them hard to read.

Ideally I would like to force the segments to come out of the left side of each label. Currently, some are coming out of the top, which is in large part responsible for the problem.

How can I force the label segments to come out of the left of the labels, rather than the top?

Here is a screenshot of the relevant part of the graph:
[image]

I want it to look something like this. I've drawn in a few big blue lines to give an idea:

[image]

I have tried adjusting various parameters for geom_label_repel, but these mostly seem to have to do with the size and position of the box around the label rather than the segment. For example, adjusting the label.padding parameter, which is mentioned in some similar questions on here, did this:

[image]

EDIT: Here is my code for geom_label_repel:

```
if (include.label == TRUE) {
    label <- 
      geom_label_repel(data = filter(plotdata,
                                     Year == 2023),
                       aes(x = Year,
                           y = Label_y_pos,
                           label = Country,
                           fill = Country,
                           segment.color = Country),
                       color = "black",
                       nudge_x = 5,
                       hjust = 0,
                       min.segment.length = 0,
                       direction = "y"
      )
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: We don't have your data, and don't know what code you used because you haven't included the [mre] that is strongly encouraged when asking quesitons on SO. You can [edit] your question to include these at any time if you want more concrete help. In the meantime, I might point out that it looks like ggrepel is the wrong tool here. You seem to have quite a clear idea of where your labels and segments should go, so the best thing would be to calculate where you think these should be and plot them using `geom_segment` and `geom_label`

Comment: I've added in code as you requested. I'm not sure it's necessary in this case, though. I'm just asking if there is a parameter I can adjust to change the start position of the segments. Surely that should be pretty universal, and not dependent on any one set of code or data.

Comment: @Falsum if that were the case then you would be able to find it in the documentation. Posting a question on SO implies that you have already read the docs and searched the internet but can't find a simple answer, so you need someone to find some sort of solution that gives you the expected output which _might require a different approach than the one you expected_. Folks here will need to test and verify possible solutions with data they know will to apply to your case. Please include the output from `dput(filter(plotdata, Year == 2023))` to your question to get the best chance of help. Thanks

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, I've checked the documentation, but I'm wondering if I've missed something. Perhaps I've come to the wrong place to ask that kind of thing, in which case, apologies.

Comment: You have come to the right place to ask your question, you just need to provide your data using the code  from the above comment. Doing so will make it much easier to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: I found a workaround, based on Allan's suggestion of using geom_segment and geom_label. I'll post it for posterity once I finish the task at hand.

Comment: @Falsum it's a perfectly reasonable question, and I have upvoted it, because I think it is a helpful question for the Q&A format of SO. But typically folks will only post answers if they can _demonstrate_ that the solution is correct. To do this requires data, and a question should not require that answerers need to create a data set to provide a demonstrably correct answer. We just ask that questions be self contained.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yeah fair enough. It's just that I'm not sure if I should be sharing this data and I don't really have time in the workday to create substitute data. So I was hoping that a more universal answer would suffice. But I get where you're coming from.